# How to determine CSS attribute is set on the element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two `<div>` like these:

```
<div class='test' style='visibility: visible;'> div1 </div>
<div class='test'> div2 </div>
```

Now I want to show me an alert when I click on *div1*, because it has `visibility` property. In other word:

```
$(".test").click(function(e) {
    if (this has visibility property){
        alert('it has');
    } 
});
```

Now I want to know how can I define a condition in the above code using jquery?

Here is my try: *(but none of them does not work)*

```
if($(this).css('visibility').length != 0) {}

if($(this).css('visibility') == 'visible') {}

if($(this).hasClass('visibility-set')) {}
```

So, there is any solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `this.style.visibility` as it will return the value of `inline-css` or empty string `''` if specified style does not exist!

```js
$(".test").click(function(e) {
  if (this.style.visibility) {
    alert('It\'s set!');
  } else {
    alert('Not set!');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='test' style='visibility: visible;'>div1</div>
<div class='test'>div2</div>
```

Comment: Worked correctly! thanks. +1 upvote for you. Just please add this line in the first of your answer `this.style.visibility`. Because it is my answer.

Comment: @Sajad, **Happy Coding**

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness and because you asked for a jQuery way. Here a solution using the jQuery prop() function.

```js
$(".test").click(function(e) {
   if ($(this).prop('style')['visibility']) {
     alert('It\'s set!');
   } else {
     alert('Not set!');
   }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='test' style='visibility: visible; display: block;'>div1</div>
<div class='test'>div2</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one:

```
$('.test').click( function() { alert('It\'s set!'); });
$('.test1').click( function() { alert('not set!'); });
```

[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/t36b4mru/)

Comment: I'm sure you didn't understand what is my question.